# OAuth: why principal id is different when authenticated in Browser and WinPhone App

Tags: azure, authentication, oauth, google-authentication

I am trying to use Google OAuth authentication for Mobile App hosted in Azure, but getting user ID (SID) in different formats.

When I access the API from **browser** directly, I'm redirected to Google login page, and after authentication the next request to my API comes with the headers:

```
"x-ms-client-principal-name":"pavlolissovtest@gmail.com",  
"x-ms-client-principal-id":"108491597139717511334",  
"x-ms-client-principal-idp":"google",  
"x-ms-token-google-access-token":"ya29.Ci9-A-oE8p4vVelYhRKqjMKY6KGxeW4OtXT-KGtBO3AxsiBqiCawn8sxL-qg4msWrw"
```

In **Windows Phone App** (authentication with WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServicesClient), when logged with the same account, request comes with different headers:

```
"x-ms-client-principal-id":"sid:3fc89f071b7cb8f18919614ac46d3636",
"x-ms-client-principal-idp":"google",
"x-ms-token-google-access-token":"ya29.Ci9-AxC3kfrYrV8ssLUkbwFJJYDPsklsUH7r3HG0f6KB_wWzXV9AqE_wGPASiYxcWQ"
```

So now I have different principal ids for the same user account.
If now I call https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?access_token=, **for both tokens I get the same result**:

```
{
 "azp": "1083509260178-cntp3794bggcs5dtkse0mtbvpqigoa78.apps.googleusercontent.com",
 "aud": "1083509260178-cntp3794bggcs5dtkse0mtbvpqigoa78.apps.googleusercontent.com",
 "sub": "108491597139717511334",
 "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
 "exp": "1476643317",
 "expires_in": "3161",
 "email": "pavlolissovtest@gmail.com",
 "email_verified": "true",
 "access_type": "online"
}
```

This allows me to identify the user whatewer login option is used, but is it really correct to call googleapis for each request? **What is the proper way of identifying the user from headers**, or maybe converting one value into another?

And what is the meaning of having these values different?

Thanks for your advice!